# Linearly Independent solutions.

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-rank

What does 'Linearly independent solution' and 'Linearly dependent solution' mean in terms of Matrix Algebra?

Comment: Maybe try google first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trust that you know what it means for a set of vectors to be linearly independent, and what it means for a set of vectors to be linearly dependent. (If not, then *that's* the question you should be asking)

Now, if $A$ is a matrix, and you have a few solutions of the equation $Ax=0$, then you can ask whether those solutions – those vectors that you have found – are linearly dependent or linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gerry. I think I will be asking about the linear dependency of the set of vectors then because that's where I am stuck.

Comment: OK, but surely if you are learning Linear Algebra then you have some text or other materials at your disposal that give you definitions/explanations of that concept.